# Add spaces inside array values

Tags: php, arrays

how can i make this code display $anchor with spaces. I would have Text Anchor1 and Text Anchor two insitead of TextAnchor1 and TextAnchor2. Thank you

```
$currentsite = get_bloginfo('wpurl');
           $sites = array(
           'TextAnchor1' => 'http://www.mysite1.com',
           'TextAnchor2' => 'http://www.mysite2.com'
           );
           foreach($sites as $anchor => $site) 
           {
           if ( $site !== $currentsite ){echo '<li><a href="'.$site.'" title="'.$anchor.'" target="_blank">'.$anchor.'</a></li>';}
           }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, as you $anchor values probably aren't hard-coded, I assume what you really need is a function that takes a string as an argument and inserts spaces before any capital letters or numbers.

```
function splitWords($s){
return trim(preg_replace('/([A-Z0-9])/', ' \1', $s));
}
```

Later, when writing output, instead of $anchor, you can use splitWords($anchor).

Answer (score 1):

```
$sites = array(
           'Text Anchor 1' => 'http://www.mysite1.com',
           'Text Anchor 2' => 'http://www.mysite2.com'
           );
```

Answer (score 1):

Ooh, ooh, my turn.

```
$sites = array(
           'Text Anchor 1' => 'http://www.mysite1.com',
           'Text Anchor 2' => 'http://www.mysite2.com'
           );
```

Comment: I was totally first.  I blame anti virus software

Comment: Looks like the other guy pulled the old "respond with anything then edit" switcharoo anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Just change to:

```
$sites = array(
    'Text Anchor' => 'http://www.mysite1.com',
    'My Text Anchor' => 'http://www.mysite2.com'
);
```

Comment: Do i have to have the same number of words? I mean, can i have 'text anchor' and 'my text anchor'?